# How to go from a viewcontroller to a tableviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, tableview

I have a `UIViewController` with 3 images and 3 buttons. I want it so that when you press a button it shows a list of possible items in the `UITableViewController` which can fill the `UIImages`. However, each list will be different depending on the button pressed.

I have tried using segues and the modal function with no luck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: please explain your problem more,

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 set of image array , on each button click send your corresponding array,
And `cell.imageview.image`  set image for each by accessing each postion of array with help of indexpath

Comment: Jeddy Gunther should accept your answer. Till now, it's still shown as not accepted.