# From ViewController to TableViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, segue

I have a question on iOS7. I have a default story board setup with a ViewController. I added another TableViewController and linked them using a button on ViewController. Xcode allows the linkage but when I run the app, Xcode crashes with the following error.

[image: Storyboard setup]

> 2014-03-29 20:58:34.862 VC to TableView[4668:60b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues
>   can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance
>   of UINavigationController.'

Why can't i have the above setup? I've tried with a NavigationController in front and it works.

Comment: The problem appeared to be your root controller needs to be a UINavigationController to make use of push segues. Drag UINavigationController from object library and placed it before your initial view controller and they will be connected automatically and now onwards you can make use of push segues.

Comment: Thanks @Idindu - Wain has the same reply but does not answer why that's not possible. Do you know why a UINavigationController is required?

Comment: push segues work only when you have uinavigationcontroller in root controller else it will not recognised the push segues.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear on the reason:

> 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

the underlying reason being: where would the push go if you don't have a navigation controller...

So, you need a navigation controller or you need to use a modal segue.

Comment: If i press the button, why can't it take me to the TableViewController?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228244/how-to-go-from-a-viewcontroller-to-a-tableviewcontroller?rq=1)This guy seems to have got it. He had three buttons and each takes to one TableViewController

Comment: And it explains nothing about how it works... Why don't you want to use a navigation controller?

Comment: Ok I agree it explains nothing. I am learning so I'm playing around and found this not easily understood. Maybe there is some UI design considerations that Apple had.

Comment: That's just how things are. A navigation controller maintains a stack that you can push into. If you want to push you use a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is really easy. To have Push/Pop Segues, You need your views to be embedded inside a **UINavigationController**.

1. Select the **first ViewController**
2. From the Menu Bar, **Select Editor > Embed In > Navigation
   Controller**